# How to fix text location in beamer column?

Tags: beamer

I have two columns in a beamer frame.
The left column contains a list of items, and the right column contains an image.

Inserting the image in the right column changes the position of the text in the left column, however, I would expect the left column to not be affected by whatever happens in the right column.

The following MWE reproduces this example (comment and uncomment the `\includegraphics` line):

```latex
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{mwe}

\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}[t]
        \begin{columns}
            \begin{column}{.48\textwidth}
                \begin{itemize}
                    \item This is text
                \end{itemize}
            \end{column}
            \begin{column}{.48\textwidth}
                \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}
            \end{column}
        \end{columns}
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

With the following outputs:

[image: correct text position][image: wrong text position]

*Correct text position on the left, wrong position on the right.*

According to the answer to [Text alignment between columns](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/390020/113035) this can be solved by using a top aligned frame.
Unfortunately that didn't work here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reading the [beamer documentation](https://ftp.snt.utwente.nl/pub/software/tex/macros/latex/contrib/beamer/doc/beameruserguide.pdf#page=129) on the `columns` environment, notice the option `T` that aligns the top of the first lines (instead of their baselines).
From the manual:

> `T` is similar to the `t` option, but `T` aligns the tops of the first lines while `t` aligns the so-called baselines
> of the first lines. If strange things seem to happen in conjunction with the `t` option (for example if a
> graphic suddenly “drops down” with the `t` option instead of “going up,”), try using this option instead.

Using `\begin{columns}[T]` instead of `\begin{columns}` then gives

[image]